# In binary search, why is my loop infinite?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search

I run a while loop with a function to check if a variable i is higher than the len of the list. I placed it there as a way to stop the loop, but it does not check it. Since it doesn't end on it's own I had to place an if condition inside that returns false.

```
def binarySearch(numberlist, number):
    first = 0
    last = len(numberlist)-1
    found = False
    i=0

    while found == False or i <= len(numberlist):
        i = i + 1
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        print(numberlist[mid])
        if i > len(numberlist)+1:
            return False
        if mid < first or mid > last or mid < 0:
            return False
        if number == numberlist[mid] or number == numberlist[first] or number == numberlist[last] :
            return True
        elif number < numberlist[mid]:
            last = mid
        elif number > numberlist[mid]:
            first = mid
    return False
```

Comment: Binary search is notoriously difficult to get right. See https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the following lines.

```
elif number < numberlist[mid]:
    last = mid
elif number > numberlist[mid]:
    first = mid
```

Consider the case where we are looking for a *number which is not in the list*.

The pointers `first`, `last` and `mid` will eventually all converge to some index. In that case one of the two last conditions will be `True`, but since all three values are already equal, the pointers are not updated anymore and we enter an infinite loop.

To makes sure this does not happen, we must make sure the interval *always* decreases in size by setting `first` to `mid + 1` or `last` to `mid - 1`, depending on the condition. We can then stop looping if `first` becomes greater than `last`.

```
def binary_search(numberlist, number):
    first, last = 0, len(numberlist) - 1

    while first <= last:
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        if numberlist[mid] == number:
            return True
        elif numberlist[mid] > number:
            last = mid - 1
        else:
            first = mid + 1

    return False
```